# SDK for building custom ODBC driver

Tags: java, .net, c, sdk

I want to implement my own custom ODBC driver to connect to hive data source. I have gone through Simba Engine SDK available for creating driver in java, c and C#. But it is licensed.

Has anyone implemented a custom odbc driver? If yes, then can you please suggest me any open source SDK available. My first preference would be to develop it in JAVA.

Any comments and answers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!